# Can I pass value of textfield to a php link?

Tags: javascript, php, html, hyperlink, href

I have this textfield in my html file.

```
<input type='date' value='startdate' name='sdate' id='startDate' >
```

What am I trying to do, is to pass the value of the above textfield into a php link like this

```
<a href='admin-confirm.php?startdate=??????'>
    <input type='button' value='confirm' name='confirm' >
</a>
```

What should i put on the href to pass the value of textfield 'startdate' to a php file? help me pls. thanks in advance :)

PS: I have tried using a form, but I'm having a trouble when there are 2 set of data displayed.

For example:

1. name: example1    [CONFIRM BUTTON]
2. name: example2    [CONFIRM BUTTON]

my problem is when i click the confirm button on number 1, the values in number 2 were sent.

Comment: You can have click function in javascript.

Comment: There are many issues with just this tiny bit of code. NEVER wrap a submit button in a link. What is the usecase? That admin-confirm is called when the button is clicked?

Comment: @mplungjan I'm sorry that should be a simple button. When button is clicked, I called 'admin-confirm' to pass the value of textfield so I can insert it into my database.

Comment: Then my answer would work

Comment: You can refer following [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14341591/attaching-textbox-value-to-a-link-in-the-form-of-a-variable-without-using-submit)

Comment: Please show us your full relevant code.

Answer (score 0):

There are many issues with your tiny bit of code. NEVER wrap a submit button in a link. What is the usecase? That admin-confirm is called when the button is clicked?

The form would work without any extra code:

```
<form action="admin-confirm.php">
<input type='date' value='' name='startdate' id='startDate' >
<input type='submit' value='DENY' name='deny' >
</form>
```

Alternative is to ajax the date when the link is clicked but you need to tell us more

Comment: I've done that form thing. But I'm having a problem when I click the confirm button every time I have more than 1 set of data. For example there's 1st set which includes name, contact, etc. also there's a 2nd set. They both have the 'confirm button'. but when I click the first one, the second set was submitted.

Comment: So have two forms. If you do not want to use AJAX, submit to an iFrame. But update your question with relevant html and elaborate what you need

Comment: thank you for your answer! I have updated my question :)

Answer (score 0):

You should do some validations to check whether the value entered is in correct format and then do the below:

```
 if ( ! empty($_POST['startDate'])){
   $date = $_POST['startDate']; 
 }
```

Hope this helps.